# How to swap a series outlet with smart outlet

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I have a series outlet that has two black wires and two white wires that I want to swap out with a new smart outlet so I can control it with wifi. But the new outlet only has screws for one black and one white wires. How do I hook up the new outlet? Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: The tabs are present on both sides of the outlet, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the little copper tabs between the screw terminals are intact, on both sides of the receptacle.  It's as easy as using twist-on wire connectors (or other approved device), to "pigtail" the existing wires.  That will leave you with a single wire, to connect to each side of the new device.

To create a pigtail.  Start by turning off the power, and verifying that it's off.  Remove the two white wires, and combine them with an additional length of same sized white wire, using a twist-on wire connector.  Do the same with the black wires.

Now you'll have one white and one black wire, that you can connect to the new receptacle.

Comment: You could also tie the switch leads in directly instead of a 2nd connection since most smart switches have wires not screws

Comment: @EdBeal - The OP says they are installing a new smart outlet as opposed to a switch. He also indicated that it has two screw terminals so the pigtails as suggest by Tester101 are what is needed.

Comment: I missed the screws

Answer (score 1):

That's not really *series*, it's just making the most of a feature on common receptacles, that lets you splice together the supply and onward wires with the receptacle itself.   It's the functional equivalent of a pigtail, you see the ground is pigtailed.   You just need some more pieces of wire, a wire stripper and some wire nuts.